# How to create QToolBar in QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qtoolbar

I am trying to add a `QToolBar` in a `QWidget`. But I want its functionality to work as if it was a `QMainWindow`.

Apparently I can not create `QToolBar` in a `QWidget`, and using `setAllowedAreas` does not work with `QWidget` : it only works with `QMainWindow`. Also, my `QWidget` is in a `QMainWindow`.

How can I create a `QToolBar` for my widget?

Comment: So you have a widget in a QMainWindow but want to add toolbars to that widget, not to the QMainWindow? How about making you widget a QMainWindow subclass? <inception horn>

Comment: @peppe I was going to give this 'hint' as an answer. Do you care doing this?

Comment: You *can* programmatically add a `QToolBar` child widget to a parent `QWidget` container. You *cannot*, however, do so graphically from within either Qt Creator or Designer. For unknown reasons (presumably relating to scarce developer resources), both permit `QToolBar` widgets to be created *only* by right clicking on a `QMainWindow` instance and selecting *Add Tool Bar.* You can probably circumvent this arbitrary constraint by manually editing your project's XML-formatted `.ui` file and adding in an appropriate `<widget class="QToolBar"...>` tag – but do so with care!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The `allowedAreas` property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html#allowedAreas-prop) only works when the toolbar is the child of a `QMainWindow`. You can add the toolbar to a layout, but it won't be movable by the user. You can still relocate it programmatically, however.

To add it to a layout for a fictional class inheriting `QWidget`:

```
void SomeWidget::setupWidgetUi()
{
    toolLayout = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::TopToBottom, this);
    //set margins to zero so the toolbar touches the widget's edges
    toolLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    toolbar = new QToolBar;
    toolLayout->addWidget(toolbar);

    //use a different layout for the contents so it has normal margins
    contentsLayout = new ...
    toolLayout->addLayout(contentsLayout);

    //more initialization here
 }
```

Changing the toolbar's orientation requires the additional step of calling [`setDirection`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#setDirection) on the `toolbarLayout`, e.g.:

```
toolbar->setOrientation(Qt::Vertical);
toolbarLayout->setDirection(QBoxLayout::LeftToRight);
//the toolbar is now on the left side of the widget, oriented vertically
```

Answer (score 2):

`QToolBar` is a widget. That's why, you can add a `QToolBar` to any other widget by calling `addWidget` for layout or by setting the `QToolBar` parent to your widget.

As you can see in documentation of QToolBar [setAllowedAreas](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html#allowedAreas-prop) method:

> This property holds areas where the toolbar may be placed.
>
> The default is Qt::AllToolBarAreas.
>
> This property only makes sense if the toolbar is in a QMainWindow.

That's why it is impossible to use `setAllowedAreas` if toolbar is not in QMainWindow.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way to properly use the toolbar is with the `QMainWindow`.

If you want to use the full functionality of the toolbar, create a mainwindow with the window flag `Widget`. This way you can add it inside some other widget without having it displayed as a new window:

```
class MyWidget : QMainWindow
{
public:
    MyWidget(QWidget *parent);
    //...

    void addToolbar(QToolBar *toolbar);

private:
    QMainWindow *subMW;
}

MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent)
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    subMW = new QMainWindow(this, Qt::Widget);//this is the important part. You will have a mainwindow inside your mainwindow
    setCentralWidget(QWidget *parent);
}

void MyWidget::addToolbar(QToolBar *toolbar)
{
    subMW->addToolBar(toolbar);
}
```

Comment: **No.** As [Kirill Chernikov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6367468/kirill-chernikov)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38392748/2809027) suggests, `QToolBar` subclasses `QWidget` and hence is generically reusable as a standard widget. Note, however, the following caveat from the official documentation: "When a `QToolBar` is not a child of a `QMainWindow`, it loses the ability to populate the extension pop up with widgets added to the toolbar using `addWidget()`. Please use widget actions created by inheriting `QWidgetAction` and implementing `QWidgetAction::createWidget()` instead."

Comment: using the `Widget` flag causes the `QMainWindow` to stop showing `QToolBar`s.